# How to logout from all tab, if logged out from one? In java.

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, session

I have developed a servlet jsp application. I am using JSP, Java-Servlet and ajax. Session also used. If I logout from one tab, how to logout from other tab and refresh the page in other tab also. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use Storage events to be notified when localStorage values are changed.

```
function storageChange (event) {

if(event.key === 'logged_in') {
    alert('Logged in: ' + event.newValue)
}
}
window.addEventListener('storage', storageChange, false);
```

If, for example, one of the tabs logs out set false to logged_in like below:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('logged_in', false)
```

Then all other tabs will receive a StorageEvent, and an alert will appear:

```
Logged in: false
```

Here actually when localStorage get change listener get called.
Then you can write your own code to logout session. and reload to login page.

Comment: 'logged_in' ===> where to set this value?

Comment: you can set any title, its not like use only "logged_in", it's the key stored in localStorage, to which we can add listener.... when you add code window.localStorage.setItem('logged_in', false); it sets key as 'logged_in' in localStorage of browser.

Comment: window.localStorage.setItem('logged_in', false); ===> we are doing it manually . DO I need to set it first.? Where should I set it TRUE?

Comment: yes in the code, while your logout function of JS get Called.

Comment: actually after logout if you wish to login all tabs after login of single tab then in login JS function you can set it to true to again listener get called. get login all tabs. for that you have to add condition in storageChange(){}

Comment: Okk... Got it. When storageChange () this method will be called? When I logout from a tab, will it be called automatically ?

Comment: If possible, please please give an example.

Comment: Welcome bro, you can, mark answer as userful and upvote. for others Use.

Answer (score -1):

To make it possible, first of all we should never use cookies to store any sensitive data like authentication tokens. Even session-cookies will not suffice since it’ll continue to live after closing the tab and even after completely closing the browser.

This leaves us with saving the token in the memory or in the sessionStorage. The benefit of the sessionStorage is that it’ll persist across different pages and browser refreshes. Hence the user may navigate to different pages and/or refresh the page and still remain logged-in.

There is one mechanism that will leverage the secure nature of the browser sessionStorage  or memoryStorage for authentication and will still allow the user to open multiple tabs without having to re-login every time.

A refresher about relevant browser storage mechanism

**localStorage** ~5MB, saved for infinity or until the user manually deletes it.
**sessionStorage** ~5MB, saved for the life of the current tab
**cookie** ~4KB, can be saved up to infinity
**session cookie** ~4KB, deleted when the user closes the browser (not always deleted)

**Sharing memoryStorage between tabs for secure multi-tab authentication**

So… this will be the only real safe way to keep an authentication token in a browser session and will allow the user to open multiple tabs without having to re-login

Close the tab and the session is gone – for real this time.